# Running Keras in R

Tags: r, keras

I've been having issues running the Keras API in R. Even when trying the canned examples at:

https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/guides/keras/basics

I get an error that simply says `Error:` with limited additional information. I am running R v. 4.3.2.

The simplest way for me to generate this error is:

```
library(keras)
model <- keras_model_sequential()
```

The output is:

```
I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\...\lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py:2976: The name tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy instead.

Error:
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to being able to run Keras deep learning framework in R is to use the free Google Colaboratory notebook. It has worked for me in the past. Here is what you need to do:

1. Create a free Google account, if you do not have one already.
2. Go to [colab.research.google.com](https://colab.research.google.com) and create a new notebook.
3. Next, go to **Runtime** and select **Change runtime type**, then from the dropdown menu, select **R**. Under **Hardware accelerator**, select **T4 GPU** since you will be running deep learning models.
4. Click **Save**, and you are done.

You can now install keras and load the keras model in your R programming environment in the notebook without any issues. Take a look at this [notebook example.](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1O3wGHSAO-rtYHU_Z4jXkN_zT2xhVNhVr?usp=sharing)

[image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is true and I use Google Colab occassionally, but there are some datasets where we need to run it on a local machine

Comment: Is it as a rule for your work or study, or simply because the dataset is domiciled on your local machine? Otherwise, such a dataset can be uploaded to Colab and then you can run your analysis or DL model on it.

Comment: It's a rule for some sensitive data

Comment: I understand now. Maybe this article can help you: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/keras/vignettes/