# R keras installation disable SSL verification

Tags: r, ssl, keras

I'm trying to install the keras package for R. `install.packages("keras")` completes successfully but I get the below error when I run the line `install_keras()`. I get the same error when I run `install_python()`, and I get the same error when I try to install keras in python itself. However, in python I am able to work around by disabling SSL verification by going into the preference dialog box in Anaconda. Is there a similar disable SSL verification option when installing the keras package in R?

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/tensorflow/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/tensorflow/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/tensorflow/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/tensorflow/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/tensorflow/

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/tensorflow/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/tensorflow/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))) - skipping

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.13.* (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.13.*
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))) - skipping

WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

Comment: Keras is one library that is notorious for throwing up errors when you are either trying to install it or use its functions in R. That is because there are a lot of compatibility issues between R and base Python when not properly installed. A solution is to run keras in Google Colab notebook. See my answer to a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77719044/running-keras-in-r/77826263#77826263